# Local Storage Error on array push

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, local-storage

I'm doing some tests with local storage. In my tests with array, i was stuck in array part (push).

What i've done:

```
if (localStorage.myArray) {
    localStorage.myArray.push("Green");
} else {
    localStorage.myArray = ["Red", "Blue"];
}
```

This returns an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: localStorage.myArray.push is not a function
```

I know the localstorage itens are always string, but i don't know how this works in an array.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage

Comment: Is `localStorage.myArray` really an Array? Try typing it in the console or looking at `localStorage.myArray.constructor`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since localStorage only takes strings, you would have to convert your arrays to JSON strings using JSON.stringify. Parse the JSON strings to array while performing further operations on the "arrays". Something like this

```
if (localStorage.myArray) {
    var myArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.myArray);
    myArray.push("Green");
    localStorage.myArray = JSON.stringify(myArray);
} else {
    localStorage.myArray = JSON.stringify(["Red", "Blue"]);
}
```

Comment: Hum, the JSON conversion is what i needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (localStorage.myArray) {
    var myArray = localStorage.myArray.split(',');
    myArray.push("Green");
    localStorage.myArray = myArray;
} else {
   localStorage.myArray = ["Red", "Blue"];
}
```

Comment: this works fine but what if the array was `["Hello, Red", "Hello, Green"]`

Comment: Then your solution would fit better. But in this specific use case split is the fastest way.